# Strange menu behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, hover, mouseover

Take a look at http://sensenich.bythepixel.com

The top menu, when you hover over "Products" and expand "Propellers", everything works as it should.

I want the Propellers to collapse when I hover away from the menu, which it does.  However it also collapses the propellers when I try to click on "Accessories".  I can't for the life of me figure out why it's doing that, especially because all other actions under the "collapse" function aren't being done.  Maybe one of you gurus can help me get to the bottom of this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should tag this with css also. Maybe someone will notice it.